# How to style a PHP generated label?

Tags: php, html, css

I have this IF clause snippet from a PHP script that is basically a small search engine:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['search'])){
    $search_term = trim($_REQUEST['search']);
    if(strlen($search_term) <= 0){
        $website_search_dynamic -> error($website_search_dynamic->label("Please enter a search query."),true);
    }else if(strlen($search_term) < $GLOBALS['_SEARCH_MIN_CHARS']){
        $website_search_dynamic -> error($website_search_dynamic->label("Sorry, you must enter at least %d characters in your search query",$GLOBALS['_SEARCH_MIN_CHARS']),true);
    }
    $website_search_dynamic -> search($search_term);
}
```

How do I add CSS styling to the two labels? For example, I would like either error message to be displayed in a centered div. Nothing too fancy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do:

```
if(strlen($search_term) <= 0){
$error[] = "Nope";
}
```

And then wherever you want in your html, put:

```
<?php   
if(!empty($error))  {
   echo "<div align='center' class='foo'>" . $error [0] . "</div>"; 
   }
   ?>
```

And style the class however you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could even try this method

```
 $website_search_dynamic -> error($website_search_dynamic->label("<span style="text-align:center;color:red">Please enter a search query.</span>"),true);
```

php can run html codes you can simple add html inline style code to work

try google and find how to add external style to php file if you wish(because i don't know external style is possible in `php`

Comment: I tried adding HTML inline styling but I get a parsing error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in search.php